# How do I split a plot unevenly?

Tags: r, plot

I'm splitting a screen between two plots, like this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(cars[, 1])
plot(cars[, 2])
```

But I don't want to part the screen right in the middle. I want the first "half" (the one with the boxplot) to be 1/3 of the screen and the other plot to occupy the other 2/3. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use function `layout()` that allows to control widths for each plot. With `matrix(1:2,nrow=1)` you define that there will be two plots in one row. Then argument `widths=c(1,2)` sets that second plot will be twice as big as the first one.

```
layout(matrix(1:2,nrow=1),widths=c(1,2))
```

Comment: And some different, but equivalent syntax: `layout(matrix(c(1,2,2),1,3))`.